# How to resolve this error Ora-25137 "Data Value Out of range" in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to resolve this error

> **ORA-25137: Data Value out of range**
> **Cause:** value from CAST operand is larger than CAST target size
> **Action:** Increase size of CAST target.

Inside `CAST` I used one column value having datatype **length 18** and then after compute again I used another `CAST` to convert its Datatype having same **length 18** but after execute I got an error as I mentioned above. Here is the code:

`CAST((CAST(col1 as number(18,0)) * 100)/col2 as varchar(18))`

How to resolve this error?

Comment: which datatype you are casting? Can you show some code?

Comment: @JINESHSHAH code has been mentioned above but i got error ORA-25137

Comment: Show the part of code that raised your error. It is difficult to figure out the reason from the information you provided.

Comment: @KaushikNayak sorry for that because it's sensitive. I can't do but this is the code that you may guess.

Comment: You need to check your values of col1 and col2. If col2 < 100 then the resulting decimal may have more than 18 digits!

Comment: When you have to do `cast` like this, it's in indication that the table design is inconsistent.

Comment: If casting to varchar2 is not a constrain you can try **TO_CHAR** for converting decimal to varchar2.

Comment: @JINESHSHAH i again try but again same problem

Comment: please provide sample values of col1 and col2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
as varchar2(18 char)
```

because `varchar(18)` means 18 bytes.

Comment: what is col1 and col2 values?